# How to stream remote participant screen sharing using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, screen

Here is my code for local participant screen sharing.

```
const videoElem = document.getElementById("video");
const startElem = document.getElementById("start");
const stopElem = document.getElementById("stop");
// Options for getDisplayMedia()
var displayMediaOptions = {
  video: {
    cursor: "always",
    height: 1000,
    width: 1200
  },
  audio: false
};
// Set event listeners for the start and stop buttons
startElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  startCapture();
}, false);
stopElem.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  stopCapture();
}, false);
async function startCapture() {
  try {
    videoElem.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    dumpOptionsInfo();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
}

function stopCapture(evt) {
  let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();
  tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
  videoElem.srcObject = null;
}

function dumpOptionsInfo() {
  const videoTrack = videoElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
  console.info("Track settings:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
  console.info("Track constraints:");
  console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}
```

On above code I get local screen sharing only.

Use case : create a room and there are two participant and both of share screen to each other and see output.

So, Anyone know about this or provide guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a lot here. First of all you need to access WebRTC API (if you are attempting to send and receive streams). Second, a signaling server is mandatory for establishing p2p connections. You have only achieved to get the user's display media, there is a lot more to do.

Here is an official [Mozilla guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols).